# PHPStan error: Argument of an invalid type supplied for foreach, only iterables are supported

Tags: php, laravel, phpstan

I'm stuck again at a point where I can't get any further. I'm working on the code of an ex colleague and try to fix the errors on PHPStan level 9. Since I am new to the world of PHP and PHPStan I need help. I am stuck on the following code:

```php
/**
 * @return array<int|string, array<int|string, array<string, int|string|float|null|bool>>>
 */
public function getFlatQuestionsAttribute(): array
{
    $result = [];
    /**  @var array<int|string, int|bool|null|array<int, array<string, int|string|null|array<int, array<string, int|string|float|bool|null|array<int, array<string, int|string|float|bool>>>>>>> $audit */
    $audit = $this->array;
        foreach ($audit['modules'] as $module) {
            if (!isset($result[$module['number']])) {
                $result[$module['number']] = [];
            }
            foreach ($module['questions'] as $question) {
                $result[$module['number']][$question['number']] = $question;
            }
            }
    return $result;
}
```

But I get this error and I do not know why

`Argument of an invalid type array<int, array<string, array<int, array<string, array<int, array<string,            bool|float|int|string>>|bool|float|int|string|null>>|int|string|null>>|bool|int|null supplied for                 foreach, only iterables are supported.`

I used a dump to show me the contents of $audit. I have changed sensitive data.

```php
array:15 [▼ // app/Models/Audit/Accessors.php:94
  "id" => 18
  "version" => "1.5.0"
  "description" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
  "previous_version" => 17
  "is_public" => true
  "icon" => null
  "image" => null
  "created_at" => "2023-08-07T08:56:21.000000Z"
  "updated_at" => "2023-08-07T08:57:24.000000Z"
  "modules" => array:13 [▼
    0 => array:11 [▼
      "id" => 2587
      "number" => "M10"
      "name" => "Dokumentation"
      "description" => null
      "icon" => null
      "image" => null
      "created_at" => "2020-12-11T13:21:51.000000Z"
      "updated_at" => "2020-12-11T13:21:52.000000Z"
      "catalog_id" => 18
      "current_question_number" => 10
      "questions" => array:9 [▼
        0 => array:20 [▼
          "id" => 89544
          "number" => 1
          "type" => "must_have"
          "action" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
          "description" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
          "explanation" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
          "base_score" => "30.0"
          "penalty_score" => "-30.0"
          "apply" => false
          "accept_previous_answer" => true
          "icon" => null
          "image" => null
          "created_at" => "2020-12-11T13:21:51.000000Z"
          "updated_at" => "2022-08-15T10:49:36.000000Z"
          "module_id" => 230
          "order" => 1
          "comments" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
          "systems" => array:1 [ …1]
          "migrated_from" => array:3 [ …3]
          "fulfilled" => null
        ]
        1 => array:20 [▶]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:11 [▶]
    2 => array:11 [▶]
  ]
  "score" => 0
  "rating" => "failed"
  "quick_audit_scope" => 3
  "systems" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      "description" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam"
      "id" => 1
      "count" => 1
      "name" => "IT"
      "createdAt" => 1692088018
      "predefined" => true
    ]
    1 => array:5 [▶]
    2 => array:5 [▶]
  ]
  "base_score" => 2415
]
```

Based on this structure, I also came up with this annotation:

`/**  @var array<int|string, int|bool|null|array<int, array<string, int|string|null|array<int, array<string, int|string|float|bool|null|array<int, array<string, int|string|float|bool>>>>>>> $audit */`

Comment: you say here `array<int|string, int|bool|null|array` that your `$audit` is an array of ints, bools, or more arrays, yet you only use it as having more arrays? I think your annotation is wrong, since based on that your `$module` can be int or bool also

Comment: @krisgjika Hello, thank you for your help. I have adjusted the annotation like this now and I don't get any error anymore:  `/**
         * @var array{'modules': array<array{'id': int, 'number': string, 'questions': array<array{'id': int, 'number': int}>}>} $audit
         */`